# Firebreath project with objective-c++

Tags: c++, objective-c

I need to incude some objective c code into my Firebreath project. The problem is that the project is in c++ lenguage. So I am trying with objective-c++ code. The plugin project name is "OpenOnDesktopPlugin", I renamed the "OpenOnDesktopPluginAPI.cpp" to "OpenOnDesktopPluginAPI.mm" and I created an objective-c class called "DistributedNotification" and I change the .m extension to .mm
I can´t init my objective-c class from "OpenOnDesktopPluginAPI.mm", I get some compilation errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DistributedNotification", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in OpenOnDesktopPluginAPI.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

and the other error:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  ".objc_class_name_DistributedNotification", referenced from:
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in OpenOnDesktopPluginAPI.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code file with the DistributedNotification class in it is not being linked.  Make sure it is in your target's list of compiled files.

Comment: Hi JeremyP, where is the target´s list of compiled files?

Comment: Do you know how to verify that my method is called? I have this code: void OpenOnDesktopPluginAPI::runNotification()
{
    DistributedNotification * _class = [[DistributedNotification alloc] init]; 
    [_class release];
     
} but it seems that this code is never called...

Comment: My objective-c project is running. I added the class to my target's list and change its extension to ".mm"